# how to update interface to MainActivity from thread activity in different class?

Tags: android

now i'm making socket connection to connect multiple client to one server. everything fine, i make thread in different class. But when i will fill textView with string from thread activity, i can't. please help

this MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static int port = 6000;
TextView txt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCommand);
    txt.setText("Server : ");
    ServerSocket server1 = null;
    Server gameServer = new Server();
    try {
        server1 = new ServerSocket(port);
        // .. server setting should be done here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not start server!");
       // return ;
    }

    while (true) {
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = server1.accept();
            gameServer.handleConnection(client);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Server  {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void handleConnection(Socket client) throws IOException {    
        PlayerConnection newPlayer = new PlayerConnection(this, client);
        txt.setText(newPlayer.getuname());
        this.executor.execute(newPlayer);
    }

    // add methods to handle requests from PlayerConnection
}
```

and this thread adctivity :

public class PlayerConnection implements Runnable {
    private Server parent;

```
private Socket socket;
private PrintWriter out;
private BufferedReader in;
String line;

protected PlayerConnection(Server parent, Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.socket = socket;

    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket
            .getInputStream()));
    this.out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            socket.getOutputStream()));     
}

public void run() {
    while(!this.socket.isClosed()) {                        
        try {
            //int nextEvent = this.in.readInt();
            line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server Receive : "
                    + line);
            out.println("Server Sent :" +line);
            System.out.println("SEND : "
                    + line);
            out.flush();
             if (line == null){
                 this.socket.isClosed();
                 break;
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
```

Comment: can you please post some of your codes? I may have to ask you if you are using an inner class to determine if you have access to the textView you want to be filled. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that you have a while loop that never ends in your onCreate method. try to move that loop in to your thread. this loop blocks inputs of your application.

```
while (true) {
    Socket client = null;
    try {
        client = server1.accept();
        gameServer.handleConnection(client);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use handler or runOnUiThread method.